# lazy loading on i18n react questions

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, i18next, react-i18next

I am working in a project where we are using modules with lazy loading to separate it, now we would like to separate also the translations into the different modules, so only the translations that belogn to that module get loaded.

currently we have the translations as it follows:

```
translations
--en
--de
--it
--sp
```

we would like to have sth like this now:

```
translations
--en
 |--moduleA
 |--moduleB
 |--moduleC
--it
 |--moduleA
 |--moduleB
 |--moduleC

etc,
```

I have been throug the documentation and tried the 'useTranslation (hook)' and 'withTranslation', both dont seem to work since they load all the translations in the specified ns anyway and after take what is received when calling i18n, I also hada look at the i18next-http-backend but the documentation do not specify how to use it very clearly.

basically I am missing some information about how to use it, but as per my findings seems the only posible solution, am I wrong?.

after installing the dependancy I have my i18n as followns:

```
import i18n from 'i18next'
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector'
import moment from 'moment'
import HttpApi from 'i18next-http-backend'
import request from 'superagent'
import {EN} from './translations/eng'
import {test} from './translations/test'

i18n
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(HttpApi)
  .init({
    backend: options,
 
    resources: {
      en: {
        translations: EN,
        translations2: test,
      },
    },
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    
    ns: ['translations', 'translations2'],
    defaultNS: 'translations',
    keySeparator: false,
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
      formatSeparator: ',',
      format: function(value, formatting) {
        if (value instanceof Date) return moment(value).format(formatting)
        return value.toString()
      },
    },
    react: {
      wait: true,
    },
  })
```

the backend key is expecting some options information:

```
const options = {

  loadPath: 'path to file',

  addPath: 'path to file',


  allowMultiLoading: false, 
  parse: function(data) {
    return data.replace(/a/g, '')
  },

  parsePayload: function(namespace, key, fallbackValue) {
    return {key}
  },

  request: function(options, url, payload, callback) {},
}
```

But I am not really sure about the way how to use it,I wanted to know if someone has experience with this and if someone can recomend any guide or documentation that might help me.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be looking for [Namespaces](https://www.i18next.com/principles/namespaces):

> Namespaces are a feature in i18next internationalization framework which allows you to separate translations that get loaded into multiple files.
>
> While in a smaller project it might be reasonable to just put everything in one file you might get at a point where you want to break translations into multiple files. Reasons might be:
>
> - You start losing the overview having more than 300 segments in a file
> - Not every translation needs to be loaded on the first page, speed up load time